# How to batch rename 40000 files on a folder with number count

Tags: macos, debian, batch-rename

I need to batch rename 40000 files on a folder with a number count in the end like this:. something.jpg to something_00001.jpg. I'd like to work with the rename command, but anything that works will do. Any Help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

These are powerful commands that will make lots of changes very rapidly - please test on a copy of a small subset of your data.

---

**Method 1 - Using "rename" (Perl tool)**

This should work with `rename` which you can install on macOS with:

```
brew install rename
```

The command would be:

```
rename --dry-run -N "00001" 's/.jpg$/_$N.jpg/' *jpg
```

Remove the `--dry-run` to actually execute the command rather than just tell you what it would do.

---

**Method 2 - Using GNU Parallel**

Alternatively, this should work with **GNU Parallel** which you can install on macOS with:

```
brew install parallel
```

The command would be:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run mv {} {.}_{#}.jpg
```

where:

- `{}` means *"the current file"*,
- `{.}` means *"the current file minus extension"*, and
- `{#}` means *"the (sequential) job number"*

Remove the `--dry-run` to actually execute the command rather than just tell you what it would do.

You mentioned you wanted an offset, so the following works with an offset of 3:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0  'printf -v new "%s_%05d.jpg" "{.}" $(({#}+3)); echo mv "{}" "$new"'
```

---

**Method 3 - No additional software required**

This should work using just standard, built-in tools:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.jpg; do
   # Figure out new name
   printf -v new "%s_%05d.jpg" "${f%.jpg}" $((cnt+=1))

   echo Would rename \"$f\" as \"$new\"
   #mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

Remove the `#` in the penultimate line to actually do the rename.

---

**Method 4 - No additional software required**

This should work using just standard, built-in tools. Note that macOS comes with Perl installed, and this should be faster as it doesn't start a new `mv` process for each of 40,000 files like the previous method. Instead, Perl is started just once, it reads the null-terminated filenames passed to it by `find` and then executes a library call for each:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | perl -0 -e 'while(<>){ ($sthg=$_)=~s/.jpg//; $new=sprintf("%s_%05d.jpg",$sthg,++$cnt); printf("Rename $_ as $new\n"); }'
```

If that looks correct, change the last line so it actually does the rename rather than just telling you what it would do:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | perl -0 -e 'while(<>){ ($sthg=$_)=~s/.jpg//; $new=sprintf("%s_%05d.jpg",$sthg,++$cnt); mv $_, $new; }'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! On mac the rename works fine but on debian I don't have the N option and I'm working pretty much on debian now. The Method 4 changes the file order witch is very important to be kept the same so I still have a bug here to solve. On Method 2 I sometimes also need to start the numbering from something other then 0 and I haven't figured out how to solve that.

Comment: I don't have Debian, but the program is actually a Perl script. It may be part of `dev-perl/rename` with executable called `perl-rename`, or `prename`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. It's working but only with folders under 7000 files. More then that it gives me '-bash: /usr/local/bin/rename: Argument list too long'. Any way to go around that?

Comment: If that is Method 1, you can use `find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | rename -0 --dry-run -N "00001" 's/.jpg$/_$N.jpg/'`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying Method1, but it returns 'Error: --null only permitted when reading filenames from STDIN'

Comment: Not sure, try adding a space then a `-` at the end, though it should be reading from `stdin` anyway as no filenames are specified as parameters.

Comment: It doesn't recognize '-' but I tried in a smaller batch and it did work with adding a space then a ' * ' at the end. But in the huge batch I returned the same problem of 'Argument list too long'.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the `rename` on your system can't cope with being fed filenames on `stdin`, so let's abandon that one. Method 3 should be the easiest for any system as it requires no additional software, so can you try that please?

Comment: (Shorter) alternative to offset 3-solution: `find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run 'mv {} {.}_{= $_=sprintf("%05d",slot()+3) =}.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer).

```
$ tree
.
├── beach.jpg
├── sky.jpg

$ renamer --path-element name --index-format %05d --find /$/ --replace _{{index}} *

$ tree
.
├── beach_00001.jpg
├── sky_00002.jpg
```

Comment: Hi Lloyd, this might work for me but is there a way for me to start at a given number, say 00456?

Comment: Hi, no it's not.. but it should be.. do you have time to add a `--index-root` option and submit a PR?

Comment: sorry, I'm new at this. what is a PR?