# Rename files with incrementing number starting at certain number

Tags: bash, macos

I have some files:

```
$ ls
00000.ABC
00001.ABC
00002.ABC
00003.ABC
00004.ABC
00005.ABC
```

I want to change these to start at a certain number, for example `00055.ABC` so the new files look like:

```
$ ls
00055.ABC
00056.ABC
00057.ABC
00058.ABC
00059.ABC
00060.ABC
```

I understand about for loops to loop through each file, for example `for file in ls { }` but I'm not sure about the incrementing number starting at a certain number so appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you expand your example a little bit? Do you want to change the digit at the ten-position or do you want to add a number? E.g. would you also need to have them start at 8? Then 0 would become 8, 1 would become 9, etc.

Comment: Because, as it stands now, `rename 's/^0000(\d)\.ABC$/0001$1.ABC/' *` would already work, but I doubt that is your actual use-case

Comment: I can see how the question might not be clear. I'll edit it. The original number is not relevant to the new number although it should edit the files in order.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51369916/2836621

Comment: `for example for file in ls { }` - well, [don't use ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), don't use `for file in ls`. It's better to do `find . -type f -maxdepth1 | while IFS= read -r file`. `but I'm not sure about the incrementing number` och that's easy. So you have `file=00055.ABC`. First extract the part before and after dot, ex. with `cut`. Or better with `IFS=. read -r beforedot afterdot`.  Then increment the number `beforedot=$((beforedot+55))`. Then `mv` the file from the original to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```sh
for f in *.ABC; do
   num=$(basename "$f" .ABC)
   num2=$(printf "%05d" $((num + 55)))
   echo mv "$f" "$num2.ABC"
done
```

Notes:

- I am assuming your files all follow the pattern of digits followed by `.ABC`, so that `basename $f .ABC` extracts the number. You'll have to adjust the `num=` line if this assumption does not hold.
- `$(( ... ))` is the `bash` syntax to do arithmetic operations.
- `(printf "%05d" ...)` is here to pad zeroes in front of the number, otherwise you'd just get `55` etc.
- Remove the `echo` once you're convinced it's doing the right thing.
- EDIT **Warning**: the new set of filenames should not overlap the old set of filenames, or you might lose some files. Carefully choosing the order the `mv` commands are run could solve the issue, but putting the files in a new directory as they are renamed and moving them back after would be much simpler.

**EDIT**:

@MarkSetchell pointed out in the comments that you want sequential numbering that is not based on the original file names, in which case this loop would work instead:

```sh
i=55 # choose your starting destination file number here
for f in *.ABC; do
   dest=$(printf "%05d" $i).ABC
   echo mv "$f" "$dest"
   i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Comment: Be careful to double quote `"$f"`. OP's comment says *"original number is not relevant to new number"*, so solution is even easier :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer with quotes around `"$f"` - I often forget but agree that's important - and an alternate solution for sequential numbering independent of original file names.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `rename`, which is actually just a Perl script, and which can be installed on **macOS** with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```

The command would then be:

```
rename --dry-run  -XN "00055" -e '$_ = $N' *ABC
```

**Sample Output**

```
'00001.ABC' would be renamed to '00055.ABC'
'00002.ABC' would be renamed to '00056.ABC'
'00003.ABC' would be renamed to '00057.ABC'
'00004.ABC' would be renamed to '00058.ABC'
'00005.ABC' would be renamed to '00059.ABC'
```

If that looks correct, you would remove the `--dry-run` and do it again. Using `rename` has the benefit that it will not clobber (overwrite) files and it will tell you what it is going to do, without actually changing anything, if you use the `--dry-run` option. It is also immensely powerful - it can do lowercase, camelcase, uppercase, remove control characters, call any Perl module and calculate any expression or substitution you can think of.