# Rename files in linux using mv and regex

Tags: linux

I have a set of files named like:

```
05.#005 file.mp4
06.#006 file.mp4
07.#007 file.mp4
```

and I want to rename them like the following

```
#005 file.mp4
#006 file.mp4
#007 file.mp4
```

what should I do to make the job done in linux terminal? 
I want to do it with for loop and command mv

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files

Comment: How much similar is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860821/rename-files-with-incrementing-number-starting-at-certain-number

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've searched already, but I'm new to linux so I wasn't able to do ehat I want exactly, Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that all of these *mp4 files are in the same directory you
can indeed use `for` loop like that:

```
for i in *mp4; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -E 's,^[0-9]{2}\.,,')"; done
```

You didn't specify what shell you use. In Bash, for example you could
use `<<<` instead of `echo`.

You could also use Perl implementation of `rename` program (there is
another program called `rename` which is a part of `util-linux`
package) like that:

```
rename 's,^[0-9]{2}\.,,' *mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for answer & for info :)